# Is there a word meaning positive envy in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to mean positive envy as I don't want to sound negative and upset the person I am communicating with.  In Arabic we say 'yaghbitu - يغبط' which means you want/wish to have the same good that the other has and that you are happy that he/she has it without any insignuation that you wish they didn't have it or do not deserve to have it.
The translation in English gives me 'envy' which is closer to 'yahssudu يحسد' in Arabic which has negative connotation.
So is there a better word than 'envy' and if not, is it safe and ok to use 'envy' in this context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a word for a positive kind of "envy" without the sense of resentment?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266611/whats-a-word-for-a-positive-kind-of-envy-without-the-sense-of-resentment)

Comment: "envy' isn't necessarily a negative feeling. I've heard it several times in sentences such as: "sunny and mild? Oh, I envy you. I wish we had your weather" or "I envy you, right now I have to work very hard and I'll only be able to travel next year".

Comment: related: [why is envy considered a sin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305411/why-is-envy-is-considred-a-sin-while-envious-is-a-rather-desirable-attribute)

Comment: Isn't this admiration?  Also, not sure if this is a real word, but check out "compersion".  Or maybe aspiration?  Aspiring to be like someone is positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically “Envy” is a feeling of discontent and resentment based on someone else's possessions, abilities, or status. “Covet” is wishing, longing, or craving for something that belongs to someone else. “Jealous” is more commonly used as opposed to “envious” However, misinterpretations can still be made. I recommend adding context

Examples:

“that’s great that happened to you! I’m “jealous”
“You got a new job? That’s great, I “envy” you

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/jealous-vs-envious

Comment: What do you mean by *technically”? The Merriam Webster link you give is indeed interesting and based on definition, followed by a view of opinion and attributed meaning. It does not support your assertion that envy is - technically or otherwise - what you claim it to be.

Comment: None of these words has the positive connotation that OP asked for.

Comment: *Possibly* more naturally: "I'm envious".  In context, this would carry the positive connotation sought.

Answer (score 14):

*envy* should not be confused with *jealousy*. *envy* may be positive. The Cambridge dictionary has meanings similar to

> envy = the feeling that you wish you had something that someone else has
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/envy)

This is not a negative verb. To say “I envy her good fortune” simply says that you wish for good fortune like hers. It is not to say “I am jealous of her good fortune”.

> Jealous = unhappy and angry because someone has something that you want:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/envy)

I conclude that you may use *envy* but that you should pay careful attention to context, particularly in circumstances where envy might be confused with jealousy, covetousness, admiration or esteem.

Comment: Other dictionaries are clear that envy has a negative feeling by using terms like "resentful" or "malice". It certainly may be true that people often use it in a softer sense, but not that it has a positive meaning

Comment: @eques: I think you have it backwards.  Envy is neutral to positive, but some people misuse it as a synonym for jealousy.

Comment: @jamesqf On the contrary, I checked 2 dictionaries before making my comment. Envy is definitely not neutral to positive at least not in *all* sources. For one, it is defined as one of the seven deadly sins. The distinction between envy and jealousy, when one exists, is not positive vs negative but rather directional. You envy what some else has. You are jealous about what you have (that you might lose it)

Comment: For example, Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envy?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld) "painful or resentful awareness..." painful and resentful are not ordinarily positive

Answer (score 10):

Aspiration/Aspire is an unoffensive, but uncommon choice.

> I aspire to your level of success.

It's uncommon partly because there are briefer (or slangier and richer) ways to say the same thing:

> I'm following your example.

> I want to do what *you're* doing! (slangy)

Inspire can also be used to great effect, although the meaning shifts a bit:

> He was inspired by Mark Zuckerberg' example to drop out of college to start a company.

---

When you are directly confronting another person about how you feel about their success, I believe the biggest way to avoid negative meaning is to suitably respect their hard work, or their fortune.

> Congratulations on your promotion! Just you wait, I'll have a corner office, too! (mild teasing, so depends on the relationship)

> Dude, you're lucky! I wish I could have that. (slangy, and calling someone lucky is risky if they've worked hard for it.)

Even exaggerating the level of your envy in a comical way can (counter-intuitively) come across as positive. If your envy inspires you to become more productive (for example), then the envy itself is a genuine compliment: it shows that not only is their success obvious to you, but it's also meaningful to you.

---

Importantly, I'm giving examples that only work in certain contexts, and are how *I* might convey this meaning, but it really depends on your personality how you want to say this. I hope my examples are at least informative, if not directly usable.

Comment: I think this _aspire_ really meets the criteria because it's clear that one _also_ wants such a state. There is no implication that the state can only be occupied by one and so they must be toppled to achieve it, as can be the case with _envy_. A position of power, for example, could be _taken_ by one who _envious_, but one who _aspires_ would receive it when the current holder leaves it through some outside process, age, or giving it up (moving up or out).

Comment: @ti7 Thanks! This was one of the most difficult answers to get right, and it looks like it was worth it.

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer to the question is one that is non-negative, that of holding high regard for the others accomplishments with the hope or dream of matching them. The term is *Admiration* to think highly of another and with the best of motives envy the bejesus out of them.

Comment: I considered *admire* but held back because of its ironic use in statements such as *I admire your cheek* or “we admire your insolence”. It is not always used positively.

Comment: ... And you can admire a skill say without the least feeling of wanting the same skill.

Comment: Conversely, I can easily imagine examples — well, fictional ones, anyway (i.e. occurring in works of fiction) — where someone might *un*ironically admire cheek or insolence.

Comment: @Anton it's meaning is always positive though. For example, a drawn out, sarcastic, "great..." would generally not indicate a positive reaction, but that doesn't change the meaning of the word itself.

Answer (score 1):

To fancy? As an alternative to imagine: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fancy

> to form a conception of /  to visualize or interpret as :

eg: I fancy your good fortune!